# Bean not being found

Tags: java-ee-7

I am trying to learn JavaEE; after following a tutorial I am unable to reach a bean that is clearly annotated correctly:

```
@Named("editPhotoBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EditPhoto implements Serializable `
```

calling a bean method using jsf tag:

```
`<h:inputFile 
    id="file" 
    value="#{editPhotoBean.uploadedPart}"> 
 <f:validator validatorId="imageUploadValidator" />
 </h:inputFile>`
```

I get:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /upload.xhtml @30,63
>   value="#{editPhotoBean.uploadedPart}": Target Unreachable, identifier
>   'editPhotoBean' resolved to null

formerly I had it as:

```
@Named(value = "editPhotoBean")
```

Something else that is telling is the fact that properties on other beans show up as unfound by netbeans:

```
            <tr><td align='center'>
            <label>
                <c:if test="#{photoBook.currentPhoto.public}">
                    Everyone can see this photo
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="#{not photoBook.currentPhoto.public}">
                    Only you can see this photo
                </c:if>

            </label>
        </td></tr> 
        <tr><td align='center'>
                <label>Uploaded as #{photoBook.currentPhoto.filename}</label>
```

though that bean is marked:

```
@Named("photoBook")
@SessionScoped
 public class PhotoBook implements Serializable {
```

I suspect it has something to do with my libraries, everything else has worked but I looked and realized that I don't have any JAvaEE libraries installed except what comes with glassfish:

[image]

any hints on what to install ? || is it something else ?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. If using JSF or PrimeFaces set annotation `@ManagedBean` on top of
   class
2. List item setter and getter on `uploadedPart` property

Comment: "ManagedBean" is not required as CDI, and therefore "Named", is the sucessor and better way.